# Optimising single-delimiter string tokenisation

Tags: c++, performance, strings, parsing, csv

I am trying to optimise my tokenizing of tab delimited strings:

```
static void split_line(string &line, input_record &rec)
{
    int col = 0;
    char *row = &line[0];
    char *token = strtok(row, "\t");
    while (token)
    {
        switch(++col)
        {
            case 2 : rec.sequence = token; break;
            case 4 : rec.content = token; break;
            case 9 : rec.position = atoi(token); return;
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, "\t");
    }
}
```

where

```
struct typedef
{
    string sequence;
    string content;
    unsigned int position;
} input_record
```

This function is called on the result from each `getline` from a parent, causing `split_line` to be called over 100 million times.

Each `line` has at least 15 columns (of which 2, 4 and 9 are useful), and I assign the relevant tokens to variables in a struct. The first 10 columns of a string contain roughly 150 characters (variable length) and I am handling millions of records. Currently, it takes ~0.8µs to process a string, and is a bottleneck in my code.

Does anyone have advice for squeezing more speed out of this?

Comment: Where does the profiler say the time is taken up?

Comment: And `strtok` is rarely a good solution.  For single separators, it's probably slower than the alternatives (like `std::find`) as well.

Comment: And what are the types of the values you are assigning? If they're `std::string`, there's probably a significant amount of copying (and rescanning, to determine the length).

Comment: @JamesKanze The call to `strtok` - the other operations barely register. I am indeed assigning to strings, although I tried directly assigning the `strtok` return and didn't register any speed-up (this is worth trying again, I may have been stupid). I will try `std::find` but, I can't imagine it is faster? Thanks man!

Comment: Write a simple (f)lex routine to do the work.  Also, can you count on the input always being tab-delimited?  What if someone silently converted some or all tabs to spaces?

Comment: As in, the scanner generating tool? Could you elaborate? For the moment, assume they are tabs. Changing it to commas would  be simple.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming both `string` and `input_record` are actually `typedef`s?

Comment: Then this is not a clean cut'n'paste. What are the ampersands doing in the declaration of `split_line`? And you have a colon on your `switch` statement. And how is `string` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the following change to your function. It does not use `strtok`. It does the tokenizing in the function itself. I got a little bit of speed up.

```
void split_line2(string &line, input_record &rec)
{
    int col = 0;
    char *start = &line[0];
    char sep = ','; // Using ',' instead of '\t' for my testing.
    for ( char* iter = start; *iter != '\0'; ++iter )
    {
       if ( *iter == sep )
       {
          *iter = '\0';
          switch(++col)
          {
             case 2 : rec.sequence = start; break;
             case 4 : rec.content = start; break;
             case 9 : rec.position = atoi(start); return;
          }
          start = iter+1;
       }
    }
}
```

Here's the test program and results from my testing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>

using std::string;

struct input_record
{
    string sequence;
    string content;
    unsigned int position;
};

void split_line1(string &line, input_record &rec)
{
    int col = 0;
    char *row = &line[0];
    char *token = strtok(row, ",");
    while (token)
    {
        switch(++col)
        {
            case 2 : rec.sequence = token; break;
            case 4 : rec.content = token; break;
            case 9 : rec.position = atoi(token); return;
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
}

void split_line2(string &line, input_record &rec)
{
    int col = 0;
    char *start = &line[0];
    char sep = ',';
    for ( char* iter = start; *iter != '\0'; ++iter )
    {
       if ( *iter == sep )
       {
          *iter = '\0';
          switch(++col)
          {
             case 2 : rec.sequence = start; break;
             case 4 : rec.content = start; break;
             case 9 : rec.position = atoi(start); return;
          }
          start = iter+1;
       }
    }
}

void test1(std::string &line, int n)
{
   clock_t start = clock();

   for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
   {
      input_record rec;
      split_line1(line, rec);
   }

   clock_t end = clock();
   std::cout << "Time: " << (end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;
}

void test2(std::string &line, int n)
{
   clock_t start = clock();

   for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
   {
      input_record rec;
      split_line2(line, rec);
   }

   clock_t end = clock();
   std::cout << "Time: " << (end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   std::string line(argv[1]);
   int n = atoi(argv[2]);
   test1(line, n);
   test2(line, n);
}
```

Results:

```
~/Stack-Overflow/cpp>>./test-507 "1,abcd,3,xyz,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11" 50000000
Time: 3
Time: 2

~/Stack-Overflow/cpp>>./test-507 "1,abcd,3,xyz,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11" 100000000
Time: 6
Time: 4

~/Stack-Overflow/cpp>>./test-507 "1,abcd,3,xyz,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11" 200000000
Time: 13
Time: 9

~/Stack-Overflow/cpp>>./test-507 "1,abcd,3,xyz,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11" 400000000
Time: 26
Time: 18
```

**Update**

If I change the `struct` from containing `std::string` to `char*`, there is substantial savings.

```
struct input_record
{
    char* sequence;
    char* content;
    unsigned int position;
};
```

```
~/Stack-Overflow/cpp>>./test-507 "1,abcd,3,xyz,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11" 400000000
Time: 16
Time: 8
```

If that is an option, that will be save you a bunch of time.

Comment: if you change the struct to char* it will not work because the tokens are not persistent between calls to strtok, you need to allocate space for the token and copy it e.g. strdup.

Comment: @CyberSpock, That is definitely something the OP has to be cognizant of. Depending on their use case, using `char*` may or may not be an option.

Comment: OP has string's in his struct so there it is not a problem. i was just pointing out that maybe the time difference is less if you have to keep allocating memory also than just setting a couple of pointers.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, noticed the bug in your code there! Also, good point @CyberSpock. I did try this, and managed to get a 2x speedup!

Comment: Please let me know where you saw the bug. I want to update the answer with the correction.

Comment: @RSahu the bug is this e.g. `rec.sequence = token` if sequence is a pointer, because token will not remain, it is a temporary pointer - instead you need to do `rec.sequence = strdup(token)`

Comment: That would be the correct thing to use if type of `rec.sequence` is `char*`. If the type of of `rec.sequrence` is `std::string`, then using `rec.sequence = token;` is fine. I have a feeling you know that.

Comment: @RSahu Yeah I see you have edited your answer so it is no longer the same I commented on yesterday, I have a feeling you know that. :)

Comment: Did you end up using `char*` as members of `input_record` to get the 2x speed up or did you keep them as `std::string` and still got the 2x speed up?

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to avoid one call to `strtok` by returning from the function or breaking from the `while` loop when `col == 9`. Of course, you don't need to check whether `++col < 10` in that case.

```
int col = 0;
char *row = &line[0];
char *token = strtok(row, "\t");
while (token)
{
    ++col;
    switch(col):
    {
        case 2 : input_struct.a = token; break;
        case 4 : input_struct.b = token; break;
        case 9 : input_struct.f = atoi(token); return;
    }
    token = strtok(NULL, "\t");
}
```

or

```
int col = 0;
char *row = &line[0];
char *token = strtok(row, "\t");
while (token)
{
    ++col;
    switch(col):
    {
        case 2 : input_struct.a = token; break;
        case 4 : input_struct.b = token; break;
        case 9 : input_struct.f = atoi(token);
    }
    if ( col == 9 )
    {
       break;
    }
    token = strtok(NULL, "\t");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was a silly mistake of mine, I have edited accordingly in the question.

Comment: @PidgeyBAWK, was that an error in posting or was that an error in your working code?

Comment: Unfortunately the posting - I renamed a few variables etc when coding it up for clarity and must have missed it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Untested suggestion: get rid of a switch. Making a decision for each token surely eats up time.

```
char * tokens[10];
while (token && col < 10) {
    tokens[col++] = token;
    token = strtok(NULL, "\t");
}
input_struct.a = tokens[2];
input_struct.b = tokens[4];
input_struct.f = atoi(tokens[9]);
```

Comment: I have tested this, and it was slightly slower at ~0.895-0.91µs. Thanks for your suggestion though, it was certainly worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

You may use some non intrusive splitting into desired tokens which is not altering the input string (strtok does). An (ugly) one might be:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

inline const char* skip_token(std::size_t skip, char token, const char* line) {
    const char* result = line;
    while(skip && result) {
        result = std::strchr(result, token);
        if(result) {
            ++result;
            --skip;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    const char* line = "1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12   ";
    const char* first = nullptr;
    const char* last = nullptr;

    first = skip_token(1, '-', line);
    if(first) {
        last = skip_token(1, '-', first);
        if(last) {
            std::cout << std::string(first, last - 1) << '\n';
            first = skip_token(1, '-', last + 1);
            if(first) {
                last = skip_token(1, '-', first);
                if(last) {
                    std::cout << std::string(first, last - 1) << '\n';
                    first = skip_token(4, '-', last + 1);
                    if(first) {
                        last = skip_token(1, '-', first);
                        if(last) {
                            std::cout << std::string(first, last - 1) << '\n';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(In this sample '-' is the separator)

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion. I'm assuming you're suggesting intrusive splitting creates overhead due to mutating the input string? I will try this as soon as possible, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of notes -- you say you have tab separated columns, but then you use `strtok` which won't actually work correctly for that if you have empty columns.  `strtok` will treat two or more consecutive delimiters as a single separator.  This may be what you want, or your code may be accidentally working because you never have empty columns.  If you want to allow for empty columns (and want them to be counted as columns), you should use `strsep` instead of `strtok`

If you should be using `strsep`, or if you never have double tabs (so it doesn't matter), you might be able to make the code slightly faster by using `strchr` instead of `strsep` and unrolling your loop:

```
char *token = strchr(line, '\t');  /* skip column 1 */
if (token) {  /* column 2 */
    input_struct.a = ++token;
    token = strchr(token, '\t'); }
if (token) {
    *token++ = '\0';
    token = strchr(token, '\t'); }
if (token) {  /* column 4 */
    input_struct.b = ++token;
    token = strchr(token, '\t'); }
if (token) {
    *token++ = '\0';
    token = strchr(token, '\t'); }
if (token) token = strchr(token+1, '\t'); /* skip col 6 */
if (token) token = strchr(token+1, '\t');
if (token) token = strchr(token+1, '\t'); /* skip col 8 */
if (token) input_struct.f = atoi(++token);
```

This has the advantage of not inserting NULs where they aren't needed, and not having hard-to-predict branches.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. With regards to your solution, I don't think it works correctly (maybe you did not test it?) For example, `input_struct.a` will be equal to everything from the 2nd column onwards. I think this may be a problem with `'\0'` placement?

Comment: @PidgeyBAWK: only if there's no tab after the second column (no third column).  Otherwise, the tab will be replaced by a NUL, terminating it.  There is an issue that all the pointers point into `line`, so if you reuse that buffer, they'll all be corrupted, but that is the case with your original code too.